# signalR Infinite load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I created a simple ASP.NET MVC app. I added just necessary file. One controller with one view (Home/Index) in the view i just have the title of the page, nothing else.

I have installed SignalR with nuget, map it in Owin Startup class :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(testSignalr2.Startup))]
namespace testSignalr2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my view :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

          <h1>SIgnalR Test</h1>

          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
          <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.3.js"></script>
          <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>       
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the project is really empty. When i run the application, there's an infinite loading. When i delete :

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

The loading is ok.

I've tried in an other similar project by adding a hub, it has been a week that i'm looking for any solution ...

Do i forget to do something ?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the network traffic using developer tools or fiddler? This may reveal what is causing the redirect loop or infinite loading

Comment: @MohsinMehmood yes I have. Actually it shows me that SignalR/hubs still downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution I moved all the projects into ASP.NET CORE. And downloaded SignalR Core.

It’s works fine

Answer (score 0):

You install signalR with js library anyway I suppose you need to use jQuery library 1.x.x and avoid 2.x.x or 3.x.x so you need "1.6.4 or major later versions, such as 1.7.2, 1.8.2, or 1.9.1."  use 1.10.2 and it work good with signalR application

For more info read [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

Comment: I already have tried all JQUERY versions. But still have the same problem